# בישול Versus שולק

Tags: words, hebrew, cooking-bishul

The Shulchan Aruch and the Gemara use two words that to me seem to mean the same thing: "Cooking". My question is what is the difference between שולק (Sholek) and בישול (Bishul)? Please provide sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rashi in [Pesachim 39a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=39&format=pdf) says that shaluk is extensively cooked, and Tosafos there [39b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=39b&format=pdf) agrees. That's pretty much the standard pshat. However, Ran in [Nedarim 49a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=16&daf=49&format=pdf) translates it there as undercooked.

Answer (score 0):

Shaluk means "stewed" for a very long time. It's a subcase of bashul, "cooked."

Yes I know, need to provide source ...

(I have a bad feeling someone could be using this site to cheat on their homework ...)